# Toggle table using ng-show expr leads to digest iterations limit breach

Tags: angularjs

Jsfiddle for my code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24317/).

There is a `notes` table with a toggle button to show or hide the table at the end. Background color for each `note` is randomly selected from a constant list of colors.

When i click on the toggle button, instead of the table getting hidden, it gets re-rendered with new colors. Does ng-show create a new `scope` on every click? And also, i am getting this error,

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
..................................................................
```

Comment: Yesterday night your problem come to my mind and I gave a twist on it. Please, check the updated answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code breaks because everytime you produce a random color in the controller then you're muttaing the model, and this fires a new digest cicle, that in turn will generate a new random color and so on... to the infinite.

Due to the way AngularJS is performs change tracking your model will never be stable if you generate random values on it, so you may have to try other approaches to your problem.

Furthermore, I have an advice for you, related to your code:

**Alwas use semicolons** to finish javascript sentences, or you'll end up shooting on your own feet.

Take a look at this: [Google Javascript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Semicolons#Semicolons)

**EDIT**

Yesterday night your problem come to my mind and I gave a twist on it:
[Here you have a JsFiddle with a possible approach...](http://jsfiddle.net/s8k3yprh/1/)

Basically I've changed the moment when things happens. Hope it helps.

```
$scope.toggleShow = function() {
    $scope.bgColors.length = 0;
    for (var idx = 0; idx < $scope.notes.length; idx++) $scope.bgColors.push(getRandColor());
    $scope.showAll = !$scope.showAll;
};
```